Websockets with websocat: How to find out what resource is running out?
I'm in a situation where I've got a TCP server and a websocket client, and I'm using websocat as a bridge between them. Everything works great until I get to about 60 concurrent connections, and then things seem to get dropped randomly. The error message websocat: Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107) shows up. The server gives an error about Broken pipe errno=32.
What resource could be running out to cause this?
I've confirmed that

The problem doesn't happen if the connections are spaced out instead of concurrent
The problem doesn't happen if I connect directly to the server as TCP instead of through the bridge

The websocat command I'm running is:
websocat   -k -B 1024000 -E --binary wss-l:127.0.0.1:7878 --pkcs12-der=./output.pkcs12 ssl-connect:tcp:127.0.0.1:7979

I don't think the problem is file descriptors, since ulimit -n gives 65535. But could there be another socket or network-related limit that's being maxed out, or some kind of resource that's leaking from websocat, or leaking from my server because websocat isn't closing something properly?
Adding -vv to websocat gives a ton of output, but I don't know what I'm looking for in it.
The server is a Raspberry Pi 5 with raspberry pi OS (debian based), and it doesn't look to be a CPU or Memory issue. Other than increasing the file descriptor limit I haven't change the basic settings much.

What version of websocat are you using?

@RobM websocat 1.14.0

Can you share the error log from -vv? I'm not exactly sure how you're supposed to do that on this site, I assume pastebin is okay

Sure, it's here: https://gist.github.com/JoeyEremondi/c6b9343035ae9879487d644ecdb7d353 I see a lot of BrokenPipe: read_done but I'm not sure what else to look for

I'm sorry I couldn't identify any problems in that log. Broken pipe isn't necessarily a problem, it could just represent clients disconnecting
